# Ignore unused local variable warnings in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I started to develop Java in visual studio code but on our legacy project there are hundreds of unused fields. I'm getting 300+ warnings that "The value of the local variable XXXX is not used."

How can I ignore these warnings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a file in the in the project root folder `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`.
Add the following line, or edit it if exist:

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unusedLocal=ignore
```

UPD: If you want edit more of your preferences, check this [link](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ls/issues/581#issuecomment-373804678).

Comment: Hi, I already found that issue but the thing is I have still different warnings so I need to ignore every warning

Comment: Check the link, you can disable any warning

Comment: Hi again. I removed most of warnings and only TODO's remain atm and this will became solution

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto Vlad's answer for those that come across this question later:

It be obvious for a more experienced developer, but I spent time looking for that `.settings` folder in a new project, unaware that I could/should just create it myself if it didn't exist. Don't waste your time like me. Create the `.settings` folder and `org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` file yourself, then add Vlad's code (`org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unusedLocal=ignore`). [That link](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ls/issues/581#issuecomment-373804678) he gave  helped me generalize to other issues.

Also, VS Code may hide a `.settings` folder that does already exist. To show it, open your `settings.json` file and add:

```json
  "files.exclude": {
    "**/.settings": false
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto simply_sideways's answer.

If above settings don't work, you can add `"java.settings.url":"/yourPathTo/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs"` to settings.json file.

Visit https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/Settings-Global-Preferences for more settings global preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Not a java expert but following worked for me in vscode

1. Open Java Formatter Settings With Preview via vscode command palette
2. It should create java-formatter.xml file in the .vscode directory
3. Based on previous answers, I added following line to the end of this file

```html
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unusedLocal" value="ignore"/>
```